# guery in bitween 3 table by relation

Tags: laravel, relation, wherehas

I have these relations

user has many products

product has many files

I want products that :
in user table status field is 1
and in file table status field is 1

Comment: use two whereHas if your relation are properly setup

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [whereHas method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) if you prefer

First set the relations in `Product` model like this:

```
public function user(){
    $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function files(){
    $this->hasMany(File::class);
}
```

And then you can mount your query using the `whereHas` like this:

```
$products = Product::whereHas('user', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('status', 1);
        })->whereHas('files', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('status', 1);
        })->get();
```

And finally, if you're using php >= 7.4 you can do the trick using [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php), which makes it cleaner:

```
$products = 
  Product::whereHas('user',  fn (Builder $query) => $query->where('status', 1))
         ->whereHas('files', fn (Builder $query) => $query->where('status', 1))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined relationships in eloquent model, then that is the query you need:

```
$products = Product::whereRelation('user', 'status', '1')->
whereRelation('files', 'status', '1')->get();
```

**Relationships**

In `Product` model

```
public function user(){
    $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function files(){
    $this->hasMany(File::class);
}
```